# Hebrew subtitles issue on Avid

Tags: video-editor, subtitles, avid

There is a weird character showing up on the beginning of each subtitle line on Avid even though the srt is “fine” and said character doesn’t show up on movie players... I’m kinda lost, could it be some Avid charset setting or a RTL language issue etc?

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Character Detail]